# Smallest Linux/BSD distribution for IPv6 testing?

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, small-distribution

I'd like to do some IPv6 testing at home, using VirtualBox. I could create a few VMs and leave it at that, but I feel that to really test IPv6 you have to scale up to many nodes.

So I wonder: what's the smallest distribution of Linux or BSD that I could use for this? I only need IPv6 support, a shell and a few net utilities (ping, telnet, nslookup/dig, and little more).

My aim is to create many small VMs, ideally with RAM-backed storage (I've got 12GB of RAM, and using multiattach images I should be able to store them in tmpfs for quicker access) and little RAM (<=64MB). Then I'd unleash them against some radvd and/or dhcp6 server to test IPv6 stuff.

Comment: You need approximately two nodes for testing basic IPv6 connectivity and routing. Unless of course you're trying to do _load_ testing, but then again a single computer isn't up to that task.

Comment: Why VirtualBox, rather than virtual environments on Linux?Something [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)-based would be lighter-weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following Linux Distros

- [Damn small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)
- [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)
- [Tiny Core Linux (8 MB)](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/)

There are many more and most of them have IPv6 support. You will need to check them individually.

Also mind looking this [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM).

Comment: Tiny Core Linux seems to be quite what I'm looking for. The 8MB version is just a BusyBox with some tools, and works directly from RAM (no install needed). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [NanoBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/nanobsd/article.html). It is a build of FreeBSD designed for embedded systems so it requires very little memory and is designed to run from small read-only media.

As an added bonus you can build FreeBSD [without IPv4 support](http://wiki.freebsd.org/IPv6Only).

Answer (score 2):

- Linux from scratch is the smallest and lightest, but it requires a lot of prep work.
- [KIWI\SuSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/) offers the flexibility as you can test drive it and specify which packages you want\don't want.
- [A ramfs with BusyBox](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs) is a hack, but it is fast and small.

It all depends on how much work you want to put in it. I think LFS is fun, but SuSE Studio is easy. The ones that peril brain mentioned are prebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Debian](http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable).

Using the net installer and deselecting all of the **tasksel** options (e.g., *Desktop System*, *Web Server*, etc.) gives you a very small base installation. You can add on what you need, *only* what you need and you have access to everything Debian offers.

My minimal Debian VM  (which I built exactly the way I described) is using only 28 MB of RAM without even spending any effort on optimizing it.